What's the default value of TCP_NODELAY for gRPC server in C++?
Is there any way to configure this value in C++ for the gRPC server?
I found method - 20grpc_set_socket_low_latency - https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Agrpc/grpc%20grpc_set_socket_low_latency&type=code
I cannot find a way how to use it.
In "Channel argument" I do not see option related with that. https://grpc.github.io/grpc/core/group__grpc__arg__keys.html
Only this "GRPC_ARG_OPTIMIZATION_TARGET" looks similar.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
